# How to process a textarea as an html list?

Tags: entities

Is it possible to process a textarea line by line and turn it into an HTML list, and how would you go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy to accomplish with hook_preprocess_field in your theme:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  if (array_key_exists('element', $vars)) {
    $element = $vars['element'];
    if (array_key_exists('#object', $element) && isset($element['#object']->type) && ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_test')) {
      $output = '';
      foreach (explode("\n", $vars['element'][0]['#markup']) as $line) {
        $output .= '<li>' . check_plain($line) . '</li>';
      }
      $vars['items'][0]['#markup'] = '<ol>' . $output . '</ol>';
    }
  }
}
```

This presumes that you have created a field called 'test' and set its type to 'long text' / 'textarea'.  Adjust the code above as desired to match your field name(s) and desired formatting.  For more information on altering render arrays, see [The Scary Render Array](http://cocoate.com/ddbook/scary-render-array).

With additional work, you could add additional flexibility by converting the above preprocess function into a Drupal field formatter.  See [Creating Custom Formatters with the Field API](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-formatters).  The [Custom Formatters](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) project might also be particularly helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the text-field and choose "list" style. Another way is to simply use filtered HTML as your text-format for your text-area. Once you select filtered HTML. use < ul > or < li > in front of each line of text to turn it into a list-item. This can also be accomplished using "Views"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however I was thinking more along the lines of how Allowed Values for select lists are processed.  Maybe even something like how lists are processed in markdown, but without having to type in the hyphens.